# How to deal with changed component hashes?

Tags: nuxtjs3, storyblok

Using Nuxt 3.6.5 and Storyblok.

After a Netlify deploy the hashes of the components seem to be regenerated.
How to deal with cached old versions in the browser which lead to empty pages?
Reload helps but returning visitors are greeted with a seemingly non-functional site (before they reload (*if* they reload and not bounce)).

Errors from browser's dev console:

```
PostTemplate.e46bac68.js:1       
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  

entry.de17131f.js:1 
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module:  
https://www.datafools.com/_nuxt/PostTemplate.e46bac68.js  

EndOfPost.vue.978fa25b.js:1     
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```